# How do I combine multiple arrays into a new array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, scope, array-push

I saved the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` variables to object properties in my object `newUpload`.  I am trying to generate my SQL update statement, but I am having trouble combining arrays.  How do I create an array that combines multiple arrays?  The global keyword is confusing, and appears should be avoided?

```
$array = array();
foreach ($this->post as $value) {
    array_push($array, $value);
}
foreach ($this->files as $key => $value) {
    $list = array('name', 'type', 'size', 'extension', 'filetime');
    if (in_array($key, $list)) {
        array_push($array, $value);
    }
}
$array .= $this->moved['filepath'];
echo $array;
```

**UPDATE:**
Mistake using `array_push` instead of `$array[] = $value`. I thought that the scope of the array was local to the foreach loop, but the `array_push` function was wrong. The code below worked. Sincere thanks to everyone - your comments really helped me come up with the solution.

```
foreach ($this->files as $key => $value) {
    $array2 = array('name', 'type', 'size', 'extension', 'filetime');
    if (in_array($key, $array2)) {
        $array[] = $value;
    }
}        
$array = array_merge($array, $this->post);
$array[] = $this->moved['filepath'];
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the how the arrays look prior to being combined and how they should look after being combined?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function to do just this called [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and to use it in your case you would do this:

```php
$array = array_merge($_POST, $_FILES);
```

Comment: There is a filter: `$list = array('name', 'type', 'size', 'extension', 'filetime');`

Comment: To mention that you can merge arrays like this too:
$result = $array2 + $array1;
which is equal to
$result = array_diff_key($array1, $array2) + $array2;
this is more for the cases where you have to not bother about same keys is both arrays